# What are alternatives of Gradient Descent?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, logistic-regression, gradient-descent

Gradient Descent has a problem of Local Minima. We need run gradient descent exponential times for to find global minima.

Can anybody tell me about any alternatives of gradient descent with their pros and cons.

Thanks.

Comment: Specially in the case of neural network.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is more a problem to do with the function being minimized than the method used, if finding the true global minimum is important, then use a method such a simulated annealing. This will be able to find the global minimum, but may take a very long time to do so.

In the case of neural nets, local minima are not necessarily that much of a problem. Some of the local minima are due to the fact that you can get a functionally identical model by permuting the hidden layer units, or negating the inputs and output weights of the network etc. Also if the local minima is only slightly non-optimal, then the difference in performance will be minimal and so it won't really matter. Lastly, and this is an important point, the key problem in fitting a neural network is over-fitting, so aggressively searching for the global minima of the cost function is likely to result in overfitting and a model that performs poorly.

Adding a regularisation term, e.g. weight decay, can help to smooth out the cost function, which can reduce the problem of local minima a little, and is something I would recommend anyway as a means of avoiding overfitting.

The best method however of avoiding local minima in neural networks is to use a Gaussian Process model (or a Radial Basis Function neural network), which have fewer problems with local minima.

Comment: On your last point about Gaussian Process, can you cite some references.

Comment: How come this answer is exactly the same with [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/97026), CHARACTER BY CHARACTER.

Answer (score 27):

See [my masters thesis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.09725.pdf#page=96) for a very similar list:

### Optimization algorithms for neural networks

- Gradient based

  - Flavours of gradient descent (only first order gradient):

    - Stochastic gradient descent: [image]
    - Mini-Batch gradient descent: [image]
    - Learning Rate Scheduling:

      - Momentum: [image]
      - [RProp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rprop) and the mini-batch version RMSProp
      - [AdaGrad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent#AdaGrad)
      - Adadelta ([paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.5701v1.pdf))
      - Exponential Decay Learning Rate
      - Performance Scheduling
      - Newbob Scheduling
    - [Quickprop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickprop)
    - Nesterov Accelerated Gradient (NAG): [Explanation](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/#sgd)
  - Higher order gradients

    - [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method): [Typically not possible](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/253636/25741)
    - Quasi-Newton method

      - BFGS
      - L-BFGS
  - Unsure how it works

    - Adam (Adaptive Moment Estimation)

      - AdaMax
    - Conjugate gradient
- Alternatives

  - Genetic algorithms
  - Simulated Annealing
  - [Twiddle](https://martin-thoma.com/twiddle/)
  - Markov random fields (graphcut/mincut)
  - The **Simplex algorithm** is used for linear optimization in a operations research setting, but aparently also for neural networks ([source](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/10/01/simplex-optimization.aspx))

You might also want to have a look at my article about [optimization basics](https://martin-thoma.com/optimization-basics) and at Alec Radfords nice gifs: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZOUf.jpg) and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D25Fj.jpg), e.g.

[image]

Other interesting resources are:

- [An overview of gradient descent optimization algorithms](http://sebastianruder.com/optimizing-gradient-descent/)

### Trade-Offs

I think all of the posted optimization algorithms have some scenarios where they have advantages. The general trade-offs are:

- How much of an improvement do you get in one step?
- How fast can you calculate one step?
- How much data can the algorithm deal with?
- Is it guaranteed to find a local minimum?
- What requirements does the optimization algorithm have for your function? (e.g. to be once, twice or three times differentiable)

Answer (score 2):

It has been demonstrated that being stuck in a local minima is very unlikely to occur in a high dimensional space because having *all* derivatives equals to zero in every dimensions is unlikely. (Source Andrew NG Coursera DeepLearning Specialization) That also explain why gradient descent works so well.

Answer (score 1):

Local minima is a property of the solution space, not the optimization method. It is a problem with neural networks in general. Convex methods, such as SVMs, have gained in popularity largely because of it.

Answer (score 0):

[Extreme Learning Machines](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/egbhuang/) Essentially they are a neural network where the weights connecting the inputs to the hidden nodes are assigned randomly and never updated. The weights between the hidden nodes and the outputs are learned in a single step by solving a linear equation using matrix inverse.